# Broadcast receiver never receives intent

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a problem with receiving notification. I am sure it is sent as I see log for sending. But I never receive it as I never see log or notification. I am not quiet sure what I am doing wrong. 
And I don't want repeating alarm.
Using Nexus 7 on Marshmallow.

**PracticeWordsActivity.java**

```
public void setAlarm(int day){
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmIntent = new Intent(PracticeWordsActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+15000, pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+15000, pendingIntent);
    Log.e(TAG,"Lift off");

}
```

**AlarmService**

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService 
{

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String TAG = "AlarmService";
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


public AlarmService() {
      super("AlarmService");
  }


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
   Log.e(TAG,"Alarm Service has started.");
   Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
   notificationManager =         
(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
    bundle.putString("test", "test");
    mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     

    Resources res = this.getResources();
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new     NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setTicker("TITLE")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("TITLE2")
                .setContentText("SUBJECT");

    notificationManager =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

Log.e(TAG,"Notifications sent.");
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
   private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
   Intent intent;
   PendingIntent pendingIntent;
   NotificationManager notificationManager;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.e(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver has received alarm intent.");
     Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
     context.startService(service1);            
   }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

I have set receiver and service after declaring last activity in AndroidManifest.

```
...
</activity>
  <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"     
  android:enabled="true"/>
  <service android:name=".AlarmService" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` to set the alarm. `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` means time elapsed since the device booted up.
If you want the alarm to be triggered 15 seconds after you set it, use:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+15000, pendingIntent);
```

or

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+15000, pendingIntent);
```

Also, I see you're triggering the alarm in `WAKEUP` mode and in your broadcast receiver you're starting a service. There is a chance that the device will go back to sleep before the service gets started. You can use [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) to prevent that.

You don't need to worry about repeating alarms, if you use the same intent to set a new alarm, the previous alarm that is using the same intent will be canceled.

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for your answer. 
I have changed it in code as you suggested but I am still not getting aynthing in receiver. 
I even changed requestCode to always be 0 but still no success.

Comment: @Lvka Do you get any errors ? The changes you've made should have at least trigger the alert and call the receiver after 15 seconds. The only thing that is missing is a call to `AlarmService.completeWakefulIntent(intent);` when the service finishes it's task. This call is needed in order to release the wake look.

Comment: Thank you for everything. You made me realize I still have a lot of to learn and things I don't understand! 
I have rewrote my code using your guidelines and now it works as it should.